Audio output simultanuously on aux an HDMI
I have a fanless mini-pc (LUbuntu 24.04) with an aux analog output and a HDMI port.
Currently I can select within Kodi either to use pulse for analog output or HDMI1 for output on the monitor
Is there any way to 'create a virtual device' which I can select within KODI to play sounds both on aux and HDMI?
fyi- found this, double audio output but paprefs can not be installed
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 pulseaudio-module-gsettings : Hängt ab von: pulseaudio (= 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10)
 pulseaudio-module-zeroconf : Hängt ab von: pulseaudio (= 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10)

Thanks for your support!
